# How to tell if Macbook is using 802.11ac

Tags: wifi, airport

I just got a new Macbook Air and a new Airport Extreme, both of which support 802.11ac.

Is there an easy way to tell if my Macbook Air is connecting to the Airport Extreme via 802.11ac?  Relatedly, can I tell if I'm connecting at 5GHz band or 2.4GHz band?

I've already done a speedtest, and the results are inconclusive.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

When you're connected to the Wi-Fi network, hold down <kbd>option</kbd> and click the Wi-Fi icon in the OS X menubar. You'll see additional details about your connection, including one item labelled `PHY Mode:`. That will show you whether you're connected via 802.11ac, n, g, etc.

[image: Wi-Fi menu with extended options]

There's also a `Channel:` entry that tells you the radio frequency and channel.

Comment: Wow, I really liked this!

Comment: Is there a way to check this from the terminal?

Answer (score 5):

Hold Option key (alt) and press on your WiFi icon.

That will instantly tell you if you connected with 2.4 or 5 Gig in the expanded menu.

[image]